# Where can I find an example of a couchDB database?

Tags: database, couchdb

I'm looking for something similar to the NorthwindDB that comes with SQL Server installs. Just a DB full of data that I can 'learn on'.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of Northwind database are available in [json](http://mono.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/customers?format=json) format as well. So you can download the file and push it to couchdb and perform all sorts of crazy experiments. To insert a large volume of data couchdb supplies a [bulk_insert_api](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API#Modify_Multiple_Documents_With_a_Single_Request).

But the problem is that it expects the data is a specific format ie.

```
{"docs":[]}
```

every document that has to be inserted must be the member of `docs` array so we will have to prepare our customers file in that format.  Luckily the "Customers" is already a list so just replace it with docs. Your final document should look like

```
{"docs":[],//rest}
```

Now we will use curl to push the data to couch db here is the code

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @customers -vX POST $DB/_bulk_docs
```

replace $DB with the name of your database and customers with the path to your northwind.json file.

If everything goes well you should see an array of documents printed on the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Not an official, but good candidate for example database with rich document's structure, real-world data and predefined set of view, show and list functions:

```
http://jan.couchone.com/gigan-couchdb/
```

Just put this as replication source in Futon, or via curl:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:5984/_replicate -d '{"source":"http://jan.couchone.com/gigan-couchdb/", "target":"gigan", "create_target": true}' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```